# Plotly.js polar plot legend bug

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, plotly

I get extraneous items in my legend if I have less than three datasets. I have a codepen example that demonstrates it.

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJNzma)

If you change line 61 to:

```
var data = [trace1,trace2,trace3,trace4,trace5];
```

then you will see that the legend has no extraneous entries. I have been wrestling with this for a while but I am stumped :(

Comment: Good catch! [Open an issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues) and we'll get to it!

Comment: I should have checked out github first :)